# Primitive idempotents of Cl(1,3) over the complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents, clifford-algebras

Simply put, I need to find all primitive idempotents of the Clifford Algebra $Cl(1,3)$ over the complex numbers. I have found some general results but they're only applicable over the real numbers. I come from a physics background so I'm pretty much doing this by hand and checking if I haven't missed any cases.

So, defining the basis vectors as $\gamma_0$, $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_3$, such that $(\gamma_0)^2 = 1 = -(\gamma_1)^2 = - (\gamma_2)^2 = -(\gamma_3)^2$, all the primitive idempotents I have found thus far are
\begin{align}
P_1 & = \left({1+\gamma_0 \over 2}\right) \left({1-i \gamma_1 \gamma_2 \over 2}\right) \\
P_2 & = \left({1+\gamma_0 \over 2}\right) \left({1-i \gamma_2 \gamma_3 \over 2}\right) \\
P_3 & = \left({1+\gamma_0 \over 2}\right) \left({1-i \gamma_3 \gamma_1 \over 2}\right) \\
P_4 & = \left({1+\gamma_0 \over 2}\right) \left({1-i \gamma_0 \gamma_1 \gamma_2 \gamma_3 \over 2}\right)
\end{align}
and all variations with different signs inside the parentheses. How can I be sure that I haven't missed any?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: By the classification of Clifford algebras, yours is isomorphic to $M_{16}(\Bbb C)$ which has at most $16$ orthogonal primitive idempotents at a time (however, there are infinitely many individual primitive idempotents all conjugate to a given by by $GL_{16}(\Bbb C)$).